# optional flag in a function

Tags: python

I would like to be able to pass extra arguments to a function and IF they are present then act accordingly (say print something out from the function), if those flags are not present, just execute the function normally without printing extra info, how would I approach this ?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say `x`, `y` and `z` are the required argruments and `opt` is optional:

```
def f(x, y, z, opt=None):
  # do required stuff
  if opt is not None:
    # do optional stuff
```

This can be called with either three or four arguments. You get the idea.

Comment: This answer and the others explain optional argument, not "flag".

I think the question was how to deal with:
myFunction (a=1,b=2,doSomething)
and in the function detect the "doSomething" flag is there to have:
if doSomething: ...
Without having to pass myFunction (a=1,b=2,doSomething=True)

Answer (score 1):

You could use also keyword arguments:

```
def f(x, y, **kwargs):
    if 'debug_output' in kwargs:
        print 'Debug output'
```

Then you can have as many as you like..

```
f(1,2, debug_output=True, file_output=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fextrao(x, y, a=3):
  print "Got a", a
  #do stuff

def fextrad(x, y, **args):
  # args is a dict here
  if args.has_key('a'):
    print "got a"
  # do stuff here

def fextrat(x, y, *args):
  # args is a tuple here
  if len(args) == 1:
    print "Got tuple", args[0]
  #do stuff

fextrao(1, 2)
fextrao(1, 2, 4)
fextrad(1, 2, a=3, b=4)
fextrat(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have default values to you function arguments, akin to optional arguments. Something like this:

```
def myFunction(required, optionalFlag=True):
    if optionalFlag:
        # do default
    else:
        # do something with optionalFlag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# z is the optional flag
def sum(x,y,z = None):
    if z is not None:
        return x+y+z
    else:
        return x+y

# You can call the above function in the following ways
sum(3, 4, z=5)

sum(x=3, y=4, z=5)

# As z is optional, you can also call using only 2 function inputs
sum(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def somefunc(a,*opa): # opa Optional Positional Arguments
    if 'myflag' in opa:
        pass # do nothing
    else:
        print(a)

somefunc('hi') # prints hi
somefunc('hi','myflag') # prints nothing
```